# Updating plotOptions bar color on a click event

Tags: highcharts

I have a click event outside my chart that changes certain background colors to make page (and chart) more readable depending on data.

I'd like this click event to also update some of my plot options.

Currently I have:

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels:{
            color: '#fff'
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how I can change this color on my jquery click event that is changing the background color of my page.

Any example links would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Series.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update).

```
var dLColor = 'red';
('#data-labels').click(function () {
    dLColor = (dLColor == 'red') ? 'green' : 'red';
    chart.series[0].update({
        dataLabels: {
            color: dLColor
        }
    });
});
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/baqwcnvg/).